# How to implement flashlight button on Android in Xamarin Forms using ZXing Net Mobile

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I am looking for a clean way to create a (custom) overlay with a flashlight button for the barcode scanner using the Zxing Net Mobile NuGet package.

I already looked at some samples, but unfortunately these samples use clean Xamarin and no MvvmCross.

The code below is placed inside a custom 'ScannerService', which gets called within a MvxViewModel (ScanViewModel).

What I've got so far:

**IScannerService.cs**

```
public class ScannerService : IScannerService
{
    public void Scan(Action<Result> onComplete)
    {
        MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity.Application);
        MobileBarcodeScanner scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner
        {
            TopText = "Houd uw telefoon voor de barcode.",
            FlashButtonText = "Flitser",
            CancelButtonText = "Stoppen",
            BottomText = "Het scannen gebeurt automatisch."
        };

        var overlay = new ZxingOverlayView(Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity.Application);
        var button = new Button();
        button.Clicked += (sender, e) => scanner.ToggleTorch();
        overlay.AddChildrenForAccessibility(button);

        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = true;
        scanner.CustomOverlay = overlay;

        bool result = false;
        scanner.ScanContinuously((scanResult) =>
        {
            if (!result)
            {
                result = true;
                scanner.Cancel();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => onComplete(scanResult));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that I created a Xamarin.Forms `Button` and that this button can't be added to the custom overlay of the 'ZxingOverlayView'.

**ScanViewModel.cs**

```
    private async Task Scan()
    {
        if (await _mediaService.CheckPermissions().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            _scanner.Scan((result) => MvxNotifyTask.Create(() => MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => HandleScan(result)), OnException));
        }
    }
```

Is there an alternative way to add the flashlight button to the custom overlay?

**Edit:**

As Leo suggested I used the default example of [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Sample.Forms/Sample.Forms/CustomContinuousScanPage.cs). I added the 'ZXingDefaultOverlay' to my page, but unfortunately everytime I use a ZXing component inside my page it throws the following exception:

Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference'

Here is my code so far:

**ScanningViewModel.cs** (BaseViewModel inherits from 'MvxViewModel')

```
public class ScanningViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly IUserDialogs _userDialogs;

    ZXingScannerView ZXingScannerView;
    ZXingDefaultOverlay ZXingDefaultOverlay;

    private Grid _grid;

    public Grid Grid
    {
        get => _grid;
        set => SetProperty(ref _grid, value);
    }

    public ScanningViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, IUserDialogs userDialogs)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _userDialogs = userDialogs;

        ZXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            AutomationId = "zxingScannerView"
        };
        ZXingScannerView.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            // Stop analysis until we navigate away so we don't keep reading barcodes
            ZXingScannerView.IsAnalyzing = false;

            // Show an alert
            await _userDialogs.AlertAsync("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
        });

        ZXingDefaultOverlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
        {
            TopText = "",
            BottomText = "",
            ShowFlashButton = true,
            AutomationId = "zxingDefaultOverlay"
        };
        ZXingDefaultOverlay.FlashButtonClicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            ZXingScannerView.IsTorchOn = !ZXingScannerView.IsTorchOn;
        };

        var grid = new Grid
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        var stopButton = new Button
        {
            WidthRequest = 100,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            Text = "Disable",
            Command = new Command(() => ZXingScannerView.IsScanning = false)
        };

        var cancelButton = new Button
        {
            WidthRequest = 100,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            Text = "Cancel",
            Command = new Command(async () => await _navigationService.Close(this))
        };

        var startButton = new Button
        {
            WidthRequest = 100,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            Text = "Enable",
            Command = new Command(() => ZXingScannerView.IsScanning = true)
        };

        grid.Children.Add(ZXingScannerView);
        grid.Children.Add(ZXingDefaultOverlay);
        grid.Children.Add(startButton);
        grid.Children.Add(cancelButton);
        grid.Children.Add(stopButton);

        // The root page of your application
        Grid = grid;
    }

    //protected override void OnAppearing()
    //{
    //    base.OnAppearing();

    //    ZXingScannerView.IsScanning = true;
    //}

    //protected override void OnDisappearing()
    //{
    //    ZXingScannerView.IsScanning = false;

    //    base.OnDisappearing();
    //}
}
```

**ScanningPage.xaml** (This is a 'MvxContentPage')

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ContentView Content="{Binding Grid}"></ContentView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ScanningPage.xaml.cs**

```
[MvxContentPagePresentation(WrapInNavigationPage = true)]
public partial class ScanningPage : MvxContentPage<ScanningViewModel>
{
    public ScanningPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Any idea why it throws this specific error?

I use version 2.4.1 of the 'ZXing.Net.Mobile' and 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms' NuGet package.

Comment: Why don't you sue `ZXingdefaultOverlay`? It has a default FashButton.Refer to [this](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Sample.Forms/Sample.Forms/CustomContinuousScanPage.cs).

Comment: Removed the mvvmcross tag, flashlights doesn't have anything to do with it...